# How to Retrieve Call forwarding State in Android througn code?

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

Is it possible to retrieve the call forwarding state on Android?

[image]

Using this code only shows a popup with the current state but I was wondering if it's possible to get the actual number that is set if any

```
Intent intentCallForward = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);                               
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("tel", "*#21#", "#"); 
intentCallForward.setData(uri);                                
startActivity(intentCallForward);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. All you need is a `BroadCast` to be tracking your phone state. Try something like this:

```
public class CallBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    public static String numberToCall;
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("CallForwardingBroadCast", "CallBroadcastReceiver::onReceive got Intent: " + intent.toString());
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL)) {
            numberToCall = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
            Log.d("CallRecorder", "CallBroadcastReceiver intent has EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER: " + numberToCall);
        }
    }
}
```